# References of code not showing in asp.net core 3.1 web application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

my codes in asp.net core 3.1 is not showing references at all, have created a book model class, and was expecting my code to looks like something like this,

```
0 refrences
public class book()
{

}
```

but it was only

```
public class book()
```

and these is as been going on everywhere in the scope of the project i created, i created two new project entirely to check if its the app but am stil not getting it.

when i tried it without using refrences, i later have errors inheriting class and some inbuilt functions.
Asp.net core 3.1 web application using. visual studio 2019 16.6.2 latest.

Comment: So are you asking why [CodeLens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-code-changes-and-other-history-with-codelens?view=vs-2019#find-references-to-your-code) ("0 references") isn't active on this project?

Comment: Yeah I think so, probably the project is not selected, I don't know

Comment: Yeah, I think so.  Probably the project is not selected , I just don't understand. Am errors using some property that is working on someone else's code. Am actually following the asp.net core 101 series, when they created a class, automatically it showed reference, mine didn't

Answer (score 2):

`Remove()` suffix in book class because it denotes method.

```
public class book
{

}
```

Comment: My mistake, it wasn't there before @ishan

Answer (score 0):

so i got a way to fix my question, i noticed that codelens as been turned off in my visual studio.
To fix it:

1. goto Tools in visual studio and select options
2. you can search for codelens in the search box and check the checkbox